# How to update the status bar style when transitioning to a new view controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistatusbar

I have a container view controller which transitions from one child view controller to another child using this code:

```
- (void)switchToNewViewController:(UIViewController *)newController {
  [self 
    transitionFromViewController:self.currentViewController 
    toViewController:newController
    duration: 0.6
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
    animations:^{
      newController.view.frame = self.currentViewController.view.frame;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
      [newController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
      self.currentViewController = newController;
    }
  ];
}

- (UIViewController*)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle
{
  return self.currentViewController;
}
```

I have a problem when the first view controller prefers dark text in the status bar but the next view controller prefers light text.

First view controller:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

Second view controller:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

I put a breakpoint in both the first and second view controller's preferredStatusBarStyle. The debugger only breaks on the first view controller, but does not on the second view controller. As a result, the status bar style doesn't change. How would I notify the Cocoa framework that it needs to read the second view controller's preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` is set to `YES` in your `Info.plist` file. This should ensure that the `preferredStatusBarStyle` is called per view controller.

Failing that, set the above plist key to `NO`, then add the following to `viewWillAppear` in each of your UIViewController's implementation files:

`if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
     [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
 }`

You will need to ensure that this is implemented in every view controller in which you need to update the appearance of the status bar.

**If all else fails**

Call the following from wherever you want to update the status bar style:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

Obviously replacing the style with your desired status bar style.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance set to YES, so I went to your second solution. I actually didn't need to put it in every view controller in the entire universe. I just added `[self.currentViewController setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]` to the completion handler of `transitionFromViewController`.

Comment: Excellent! Yeah, you could call that from a bunch of methods. Makes sense to call it from where you're handling the view transitions. Glad you got it fixed.